# Ubuntu 18.04 TP-LINK Archer T3U is not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, tp-link

I already read [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134101/tp-link-archer-t3u-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04) and tried some things. 
Before the TP-LINK T3U, I had a TP-LINK TLWN32N with a very weak signal. 
With T3U, there's a No wifi symbol in the upper right corner.

**1) wificheck**

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

```
lsusb
```

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:012d TP-Link 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net
```

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8554]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

```
lspci
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity 2 [Radeon HD 7480D]
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
01:05.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 61)
01:05.1 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 61)
01:05.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 63)
01:05.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev 46)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

```
rfkill list all
```

nothing

```
dmesg | grep -i firmware
```

```
[    0.265046] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.275873] acpi PNP0A03:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.021719] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 50.0.1 / 17!
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

**2) `cat /proc/version`**

```
Linux version 5.3.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-013) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020
```

**3) /usr/src contents ..**

```
8822bu-1.1/
linux-headers-5.3.0-45/
linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic/
linux-headers-5.3.0-46/
linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic/
rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0/
rtl8821cu-5.2.4/
rtl8822bu/
```

**4) `/lib/modules contents`**

```
5.0.0-23-generic/
5.0.0-37-generic/
5.3.0-26-generic/
5.3.0-28-generic/
5.3.0-40-generic/
5.3.0-42-generic/
5.3.0-45-generic/
5.3.0-46-generic/
```

**5)`/var/lib/dkms contents`**

```
8822bu/
dkms_dbversion
rtl8812au/
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/
```

+++ `sudo lshw -class network` command returns "USB" and waits for something.

Please help me to uninstall the wrong things and properly install this driver.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo modprobe 8822bu && dmesg | grep 8822` Is Secure Boot turned off in your BIOS/EFI? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Secure Boot is turned off in my BIOS/EFI

Comment: Is https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/blob/5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a/README.md of any help?

Comment: On the one hand, I have removed remaining rtl88* (1- in /var/lib/dkms and 2- in /lib/modules/../updates/dkms then boot and sudo /sbin/depmod -a)
On the other hand, I have upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 version to 5.3.0-47-generic.
It works! : now sudo dkms status command shows this result
rtl88x2bu, 5.3.1, 4.15.0-97-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.3.1, 5.3.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.3.1, 5.3.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
hope it helps someone..
Many thanks to chili555 and Jeremy31