# TP-LINK Archer T3U AC1300 Mini after Ubuntu update on 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, kernel

## Original Question

Three days ago my TP-LINK Archer T3U AC1300 Mini suddenly stopped working on after an automatic
update of Ubuntu. Furthermore the system refused to completely shut down if the wifi stick was plugged in.

lsusb shows the stick but it does not work with the driver I installed previously

lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:012d

described here in the second answer

[Proper way of installing wifi drivers (rtl8822bu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178802/proper-way-of-installing-wifi-drivers-rtl8822bu)

I've tried to reinstall the driver but no success.

Also I tested this driver as suggested here in the accepted answer

[TP-LINK Archer T3U not working in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134101/tp-link-archer-t3u-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04)

The output of the following command shows the updated made in the last 3 days

```
find /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -name \*.list -mtime -3 | sed 's#.list$##;s#.*/##'
linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.0
ssh-import-id
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-53-generic
linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic
linux-modules-5.3.0-53-generic
libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64
linux-headers-5.3.0-53
linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic
openssh-server
ncurses-term
netplan.io
libkmod2:amd64
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic
linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic
libnetplan0:amd64
linux-generic-hwe-18.04
kmod
nplan
openssh-sftp-server
linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
dmsetup
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
linux-headers-5.3.0-53-generic
```

## Edit

The requested outputs

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [103c:158b]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [103c:158b]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

```
lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046a:0011 Cherry GmbH G83 (RS 6000) Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:012d  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 145f:021f Trust 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your original post with the output of `lsb_release -d ; lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`.

Comment: @emk2203 I have added the outputs. From what I understand the stick is not recognized as a PCI device allthough its seen as an USB device.