# TP-Link Archer T3U Plus USB adapter

Tags: wireless

Cannot make this wireless adapter work on Ubuntu 20.04... please help.

I've tried this: [TP-LINK Archer T3U not working in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134101/tp-link-archer-t3u-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04)
and now lsusb sees the device, but still doesn't work.

lsusb:
`Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2357:0138 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC`

uname -r:
`5.4.0-39-generic`

Edit: It works on my other computer with Ubuntu 18.04 using T2U Plus driver from here: https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver

But it does not work with Ubuntu 20.04...

sudo modprobe 88x2bu: Gives nothing.

modinfo 88x2bu | grep -e version -e 0138 :

```
version:        v5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a
srcversion:     9C5282368F93050B7206C8D
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
```

dmesg | grep 88x2 :

```
[ 8087.334869] 88x2bu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 8087.336610] 88x2bu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 8087.341389] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88x2bu
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "But it does not work with Ubuntu 20.04" How so? Does it not compile correctly? Does it try to connect but fail? Or what? Please provide details.

Comment: "How so? " I don't know, simply nothing happens. lsusb sees the device, but it does not appear on the wifi settings.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe 88x2bu` and also: `modinfo 88x2bu | grep -e version -e 0138` and, finally: `dmesg | grep 88x2`

Comment: Did you install this with dkms? `sudo dkms status` If so, we'll need to remove the inoperative driver before we reinstall another. Notice that your 2357:0138 device insn't covered by the driver you installed.

Comment: "Did you install this with dkms?" This one no, but before yes, I tried several things. But I removed it, I think, ```sudo dkms status``` outputs nothing.

Comment: This method worked on my son's laptop with Ubuntu Mate 20.04. So, do I have to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Does it work with the same driver version and the exact same chipset from `lsusb` ? Almost all USB wireless manufacturers change the chipset and maybe only add V.2 on the device. Please check lsusb with your son. All T3Us are not equal.

Comment: My son's lsusb: ```ID 2357:0138 TP-Link```

Comment: Ah, haaaa!!! I see it now! I will be posting an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please notice at the git repository that you linked:

[image]

Your son is evidently using the latest (5 or less days ago) version and you are not.

Since dkms status returned nothing, we conclude that you installed with sudo make install. Let's remove the inoperative driver, update it and reinstall:

```
cd ~/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/
sudo make uninstall
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

After each kernel update, you must recompile:

```
cd ~/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

**EDIT**: As we have seen, the git pull step was ineffective as you downloaded the zip file rather than obtaining the driver by git clone.

Please do:

```
cd ~/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver-master
```

Or whatever the name of the previously downloaded and extracted driver file is. Next:

```
sudo make uninstall
cd ..
sudo rm -r RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver-master
```

Now. we'll download a fresh copy with updates that drive your device. With a temporary working internet connection, please do:

```
wget https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: Thanks, I did both steps, but still nothing happens.

Comment: Please show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe 88x2bu` and also: `modinfo 88x2bu | grep -e version -e 0138` and, finally: `dmesg | grep 88x2`

Comment: sudo modprobe 88x2bu: Nothing.  
modinfo 88x2bu | grep -e version -e 0138 :  
`version:        v5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a
srcversion:     9C5282368F93050B7206C8D
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int`  
dmesg | grep 88x2 :  
`[ 5581.961733] 88x2bu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 5581.962891] 88x2bu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 5581.967004] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88x2bu`

Comment: Please disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI and report back.

Comment: Also, please confirm that when you did the `git pull` step, that you had a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or someother means. Were there any errors along the way? Warnings are probably OK.

Comment: Secure Boot has been always disabled. `git pull` gives `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` but is this a problem? I am using the most recent driver, the one I have used on my son's computer. No other errors, several warnings.

Comment: It certainly *IS* a git repository. https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver Are you quite certain that you changed directories (cd) to the location of the driver you downloaded? Did you download by git or the zip file?

Comment: Yes I have changed directory. Zip file.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Thanks for the new steps, I did everything but again it doesn't work. The zip file I had used was already the most recent version...

Comment: Your version doesn't include your device: "modinfo 88x2bu | grep -e version -e 0138" contains no reference to your 2357:0138 device. The zip I downloaded just now says: "$ modinfo 88x2bu | grep 0138
alias:          usb:v2357p0138d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*" If your version doesn't include the modalias for your device, then you cannot have the latest version.

Comment: This is strange. The result of "grep -r 0138" is: `os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c: {USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x2357, 0x0138, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff), .driver_info = RTL8822B}, /* TP-Link Archer T3U Plus */` and `88x2bu.mod.c:MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v2357p0138d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*");`

Comment: Yes, indeed. So how is it, if you downloaded a fresh copy of the zip and compiled it, then the modalias doesn't appear in `modinfo 88x2bu | grep 0138` It does for me: https://i.postimg.cc/d1hcRwG2/Screenshot-from-2020-07-05-09-19-18.png

Comment: Yes, the same zip file in two computers, it appears in one computer only.

Comment: What does this report? `modinfo 88x2bu | grep version` The same from your son, please. We hope we see: v5.6.1.6_35492.20191025_COEX20180928-6a6a in both.

Comment: I have repeated once more the same uninstall/install process from your answer and now it is working! The only thing I did differently is that I have removed, before the all process, my old wireless adapter (Sitecom WL-608). I will mark your answer as solved. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working by any means.

Comment: with wget tutorial it works like a charm! thank you very much! but need to install gcc package before `make` command - `sudo apt install gcc`

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and with a temporary internet connection run:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install git linux-headers-generic dkms 
git clone "https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git" /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git
sed -i 's/PACKAGE_VERSION="@PKGVER@"/PACKAGE_VERSION="git"/g' /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git/dkms.conf
dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v git
dkms autoinstall
```

Comment: What is this? It certainly is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is recommended by the [TP-link community](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/208022). It works for me.

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Answer (score 0):

TP-Link ARCHER T3U PLUS works automatically under Ubuntu 23.4 (GERMAN): Anwendungen > WLAN > Verfügbare Verbindungen (HotSpots) > password.