# TP-Link Archer T3U driver stops working after each system update

Tags: networking, drivers, tp-link

TP-Link Archer T3U driver stops working after each system update.

I'm new to ubuntu. After each time, I was doing the whole steps of uninstalling-removing-downloading-installing.
Only today I found out that I can only do the last two steps to make it work again:

```
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

It's a hassle that I need to reinstall the driver after almost every system update.
What can I do to fix this so I don't have to reinstall the driver after system updates?

Thanks in advance.

The steps I was following was mentioned last in this; [TP-Link Archer T3U Plus USB adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256006/tp-link-archer-t3u-plus-usb-adapter)

Comment: https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/596-pros-and-cons-dkms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the old driver. Please do:

```
cd ~/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver-master
```

Or whatever the name of the previously downloaded and extracted driver file is. Next:

```
sudo make uninstall
cd ..
sudo rm -r RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver-master
```

Now let's install dkms and git:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y dkms git
```

Dynamic Kernel Module Support (DKMS) is a program/framework that enables generating Linux kernel modules whose sources generally reside outside the kernel source tree. The concept is to have DKMS modules automatically rebuilt when a new kernel is installed.

Now let's install a new driver using dkms that will automagically rebuild and reinstall after every kernel update:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Also worked in Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04. (Using the Archer T3U Plus.)